# Can you handle compile time errors in c++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

My project has a function that clears the terminal, which is implemented using the curses library. Compiling with the `-lcurses` flag works fine, but compiling without yeilds

```
/tmp/cc3T2MVI.o: In function `ClearScreen()':
clear_term.cpp:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `cur_term'
clear_term.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `setupterm'
clear_term.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `tigetstr'
clear_term.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `putp'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is obviously expected because it cant find the library, but because this functionality is supplemental it would be preferable to define `ClearScreen()` as an empty function than to have compilation fail. I know that I put the function definition in a `#ifdef` block but I don't know any flags defined by curses.

Is it possible to catch these errors and instead define `ClearScreen()` as an empty function?

Comment: This is actually a linker error, and not a compiler error. A C++ compiler usually produce one `.o` (or `.obj`) file per `.cpp` file it treats, and the linker gather all the `.o` to form either a library (dynamic or static) or an executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a macro in the Makefile:

```
use_curses=1
FLAGS+=-DUSING_MAKEFILE
ifeq ($(use_curses),0)
    FLAGS+=-DNO_NCURSES
else
    LIBS+=-lcurses
endif
```

And in the code:

```
#ifndef USING_MAKEFILE
#       error "Please use provided Makefile to compile!"
#endif

#ifdef NO_CURSES
        void ClearScreen() { }
#endif
```

Comment: You need to `#include <curses.h>` for that. If libcurses is not installed, this will fail to compile.

Comment: This is defined in `term.h` for me, so it is defined regardless of the `-lcurses` flag

Comment: I have a make file included, but this is for a school project , and i'm worried the teacher will just put all files in xcode/textmate or just do g++ *.cpp, even though i included instructions on how to use make.

Comment: @everett1992, if your hw is not to solve this problem, you can remind your professor to use the makefile. updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is a linker error.  And no, it can't really be caught at compile time.  But one possibility would be to load the shared object dynamically in `ClearScreen`.  If it failed to load the library, then it could just return.  Doing the check at run time may be preferable to build time checks if you are not guaranteed to be building the binary on the target system on which it will ultimately be running.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do (configuring the project with respect to dependencies) — is the classical task of build systems.

For example, with [CMake](http://cmake.org/), you'll have `FindCurses` module, which defines `CURSES_FOUND` preprocessor variable (if it founds the library).

With [GNU Autotools](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/automake/) you'll have similar macro, consult the relevant documentation.

If you're using your own build system — then you have to manually code the handling of relevant flags in configuration time.

Answer (score 0):

You *really* need this library.
Maybe it will help you: http://linux.die.net/man/3/tigetstr

Answer (score 0):

Your build script should detect whether a suitable version of curses is present on the build machine. You can generate such script with GNU Autotools for example (the result iwould be a familiar `configure` script. You can also write a simple custom script in`sh`/`bash`.

Comment: This is for a school project, I've included a makefile and instructions to use it, but I'm worried the teacher might just drop all .h and .cpp files in visual studio/textmate or run g++ *.cpp or something similar.

Comment: It is safe to assume that there will be no curses installed on a Windows machine, so just check for WIN32 defined. On top of that you can check for a macro like HAVE_CURSES. If undefined, default for 0 on Windows and 1 for known Unix-like systems. If the teacher knows how to install curses on Winsows, she will know to add `-DHAVE_CURSES` to the compiler flags.

Comment: I already check for windows, and implement a different function

Answer (score 0):

The problem you haven't considered is that your code probably #include's ncurses.h, which won't ever work without the library being installed where the compiler can find it.

Comment: @everett1992 which are both non-standard headers. Especially `term.h` which is not available on Windows for example.

Comment: I check for windows and implement a different function. I just tried compilling on my schools redhat computers and it complained about no term.h, so i guess i need more checks.